# Trouble building SQLite.Interop.dll and System.Data.SQLite on macOS for ARM64 architecture

Tags: .net, macos, sqlite, interop, arm64

I'm encountering difficulties building the SQLite.Interop.dll and System.Data.SQLite library on macOS for the ARM64 architecture (M1 Mac). I'm using a MacBook with an M1 chip and trying to build these components from the SQLite source code to integrate SQLite into my .NET project.

Specifically, I'm following the instructions provided on the SQLite website and have downloaded the source code (sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.115.5.zip). After extracting the source code, I've attempted to compile the Interop.dll file using the compile-interop-assembly-release.sh script and then build the System.Data.SQLite library using the dotnet build -c Release command.

However, during the build process, I encounter errors such as "Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project" or "Root element is missing" and I'm unable to generate the necessary SQLite.Interop.dll and System.Data.SQLite.dll files.

I've tried various solutions found online but haven't been successful in resolving these issues. Can anyone provide step-by-step instructions or guidance on how to correctly build these components on macOS for the ARM64 architecture?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I downloaded the source code for SQLite from the official website and extracted it on my M1 MacBook.
I followed the provided instructions to compile the Interop.dll file using the compile-interop-assembly-release.sh script.
After that, I attempted to build the System.Data.SQLite library using the dotnet build -c Release command, as instructed.
However, during the build process, I encountered errors such as "Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project" or "Root element is missing".

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide the project file you want to build.
For example:
dotnet build -c Release System.Data.SQLite.NetStandard21.csproj